# My form won't submit?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, email

I am 100% sure this is a stupid question, but please, help! All I want is a form that will send the results to an email address. I set up the form (using jquery to hide/show fields as needed and to provide toolkit info to some of the fields) and everything works great except when you hit "submit".....nothing happens! I've put the page through http://validator.w3.org/ and it tells me that my opening form tag isn't closed and that my closing form tag is detected, but no opening form tag is, so I guess for some reason they aren't connecting? What horrendously dumb thing am I doing wrong?

Here's my html:

```
<form method="post" action="MAILTO:lawrk385@newschool.edu" enctype="text/plain">
<div class="column2">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Name:
                <input type="text" required size="30" maxlength="60" name="name">
                <p>Email:
                    <input type="text" required size="30" maxlength="60" name="name">
                    <p>Phone Number:
                        <input type="text" required size="30" maxlength="60" name="name">
                        <p>Gender:
                            <input type="radio" required name="gender" value="Female">Female
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male</li>
        <li>
            <p>Street Address:
                <input type="text" required size="30" maxlength="60" name="name">
                <p>City:
                    <input type="text" required size="30" maxlength="60" name="name">
                    <p>State:
                        <input type="text" required size="2" maxlength="2" name="state">
                        <p>Zip Code:
                            <input type="text" required size="6" maxlength="6" name="name">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
    <h4>Order Information</h4>

<div class="line"></div>
<div class="column2">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>Product:
                <select id="product" name="product">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <option value="1">Samue</option>
                    <option value="2">Robe</option>
                    <option value="3">Jubon</option>
                    <option value="4">Rakusu</option>
                    <option value="5">Support Cushion</option>
                    <option value="6">Zafu</option>
                    <option value="7">Zabuton</option>
                </select>
                <p>Amount:
                    <select name="Amount" required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="samue_measurements">
                <p>Size:
                    <select name="size">
                        <option>XS</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>L</option>
                        <option>XL</option>
                    </select>
                    <p>Color:
                        <select name="color">
                            <option>Denim Sky</option>
                            <option>Artichoke Hemp</option>
                            <option>Leaf Hemp</option>
                            <option>Navy Hemp</option>
                            <option>Sand Hemp</option>
                            <option>Smoke Hemp</option>
                            <option>Bark Twill</option>
                            <option>Navy Twill</option>
                            <option>Olive Twill</option>
                            <option>Stone Twill</option>
                            <option>Wine Twill</option>
                        </select>
            </div>
            <div id="robe_measurements">
                <p>Chest:
                    <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/chest.jpg"><br />Measure chest at widest point.</span></a>

                    <p>Waist:
                        <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/waist.jpg"><br />Measure waist at narrowest point.</span></a>

                        <p>Hip:
                            <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/hip.jpg"><br />Measure hip at widest point.</span></a>

                            <p>Center Front:
                                <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/centerfront.jpg"><br />Measure neck to waist.</span></a>

                                <p>Waist to Floor:
                                    <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/waisttofloor.jpg"><br />Measure from waist to floor.</span></a>

                                    <p>Arm Length:
                                        <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/armlength.jpg"><br />Place arm on hip. Measure outside of arm from neck to wrist.</span></a>

                                        <p>Color:
                                            <select name="color">
                                                <option>Navy Hemp</option>
                                                <option>Sand Hemp</option>
                                                <option>Smoke Hemp</option>
                                                <option>Bark Twill</option>
                                                <option>Navy Twill</option>
                                                <option>Stone Twill</option>
                                            </select>
            </div>
            <div id="rakusu_measurements">
                <p>Strap Length:
                    <input type="text" required size="10" maxlength="15" name="name"><a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><sup>?</sup><span><img width="200px" height="auto" src="img/straplength.jpg"><br />Measure around neck to where top of rakusu front should land.</span></a>

                    <p>Material:
                        <select name="material">
                            <option>Linen</option>
                            <option>Cotton</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>Ring:
                            <select name="material">
                                <option>None</option>
                                <option>Birch</option>
                                <option>Maple</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
            <div id="jubon_measurements">
                <p>Size:
                    <select name="size">
                        <option>XS</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>L</option>
                        <option>XL</option>
                    </select>
                    <p>Body Material:
                        <select name="material">
                            <option>Organic Fleece</option>
                            <option>Organic Thermal</option>
                            <option>Cotton</option>
                            <option>Fleece</option>
                            <option>Thermal</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>Collar Material:
                            <select name="material">
                                <option>Twill</option>
                                <option>Silk</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
    <h4>Additional Comments</h4>

<div class="line"></div>
<div style="text-align:center; padding:2em;">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;padding:2em;">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
```

I've put everything up on jsfiddle, for some reason my toggle isn't working, although it works fine on the site itself. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/HMfWc/ (updated more accurate code)

Comment: the validator expects inputs to be self closed. `<input>` should be `<input />` it will also correct the highlighting and indenting in jsfiddle.

Comment: you are also not closing a whole heap of <p> tags. not sure why.

Comment: @rlemon — In HTML the `/` is either invalid or useless, and end tags for `p` elements are optional. Your comments are true only for XHTML.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: I've tried this myself a few times. `mailto` actions don't tend to work that well - IE puts a warning up about it and you can't guarantee people will accept; Chrome just opens the email client. Honestly, you'd be far better off using PHP's `mail()` function with the form data you get. Gives you more customisation of the email you get as well. Here's a tutorial from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mail.asp).

Comment: @Quentin [According to W3C's Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p-tags) you are wrong; closing `p` tags can only be omitted under certain circumstances. Being followed immediately by an `input` tag is **not** one of those circumstances according to the spec.

Comment: @TylerH — Usually, when someone is using paragraphs within a form (which is questionable to start with) they want the `input` **inside** the paragraph, so it is fine.

Comment: @CaolanEvans Thanks so much for the link! A professor told me I'd be able to do mailto so I was so convinced of it I didn't even think of using anything else . . . thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

[`mailto:` form actions don't work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). You need to set the `action` to an HTTP (or HTTPS) URL and process the data with a server side program (which can email the data to you if you like) written in the language of your choice (or by a third party).

You will also need to remove `enctype="text/plain"` as this encoding is not reliably machine parseable and form handler libraries do not generally recognise that in it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response! I guess I was looking at an outdated guide to making forms -__- I'll do that!